# get a variable from php using ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

this code doesn't work for me ! i want to display the variable $nom in a notification using UIkit .
here the php file (verif1.php) :

```
<?php



$IMEI = $_GET['IMEI'];
$region = $_GET['region'];
$numero = $_GET['numero'];
$nom = $_GET['nom_client'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

/* <input type="hidden" id="nom" value="valeurDeMariable"> </input> */

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO client ( nom_client,IMEI,numero ) VALUES ('$nom',$IMEI,$numero)";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully pour "."$nom";
    echo json_encode(array('nom' => $nom ));
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;


?>
```

`
AND HERE's the javascript code :

```
<script language="Javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'verif1.php',
    type: 'POST',

    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "varA": nom
    },

    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Items added');
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
</script>
<script language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        ui.notify('Notification 01', 'Cette premiere notification s\'affichera quelques secondes puis disparaitra.')
            .effect('slide');

        setTimeout(function() {
            ui.notify('Notification 02', 'Cette deuxieme notification s\'affichera plus longtemps que la premiere.')
                .closable()
                .hide(8000)
                .effect('slide');


        }, 200);
    }, 200);


});
</script>
```

the problem is that $.ajax function doesn't show anything and i don't know how to know if it's working or not!!
please help :)

Comment: $nom = $_POST['varA']; try this remove all other $_GET's it won't work

Comment: Since your request type in ajax call is "POST", hence you need to use either $_POST or $_REQUEST in php file (verif1.php)

Comment: Since you do not pass any GET parameters from js to php, the php file will throw an error when trying to query the database. Pass all those required parameters and you should at least see some output.

Comment: the other $_GET are used to get those variables from the form on another file but i've tried your $_POST in my php file but still doesn't work :\

Comment: i don't really know how to fix it BUT HERE's the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing:

Replace all $_GET with $_POST

Because, you have chose `post` method in:  `type: 'POST',`

```
$IMEI = $_GET['IMEI'];
$region = $_GET['region'];
$numero = $_GET['numero'];
$nom = $_GET['nom_client'];
```

To:

```
$IMEI = $_POST['IMEI'];
$region = $_POST['region'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$nom = $_POST['nom_client'];
```

Also, from the code you have provided:

```
data: {"varA": nom},
```

Where is `nom` defined?

Comment: nom is defined in the file verif1.php (i'm a starter in this field so please help me )

Answer (score 0):

i have a form

```
<div id="content">
            <form method="get" action="verif1.php">
                <b><label for="IMEI">Veuillez entrer votre IMEI : </label></b>
                <input type="string" id="IMEI" name="IMEI"/><br /><br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<b><label for="nom_client">Veuillez entrer votre nom : </label></b>
                <input type="string" id="nom_client" name="nom_client"   /><br /><br />
                <b><label for="region">Veuillez entrer votre région : </label></b>
                <input type="string" id="region" name="region"   /><br /><br />
                <b><label for="numero">Veuillez entrer votre numéro : </label></b>
                <input type="string" id="numero" name="numero"   /><br /><br />

                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
            </form>

        </div>
```

and from this form i go directly to verif1.php so idon't really know how to erase those $_GET